# Why does the lower case 'r' in Google Sans font change size depending on the next letter?

Tags: fonts, typefaces, google, ligatures

I recently switched to the GMail redesign where Google Sans is used for the subject text when displaying emails.

[image]

I noticed that where a lower case 'r' is followed by a 't' - as in 'Start' - the 'r' is taller than the 'a' before it. However where it is followed by an 'a' - as in 'preparations' - the two letters are the same height.

When trying to select the word with the mouse, the 'r' and 't' could not be selected separately, so presumably there is a ligature. Why would the size of the 'r' increase next to a 't' but not other letters?

Comment: I've also noticed this... https://i.imgur.com/m15bBLH.png

Comment: I noticed that too, and I don't like it either. Firefox displays 'r' taller, too, but IE11/Edge do not. Someone decided it is the correct way to display the letter. The problem shows when 'r' is followed by 'f', because it too has a dash in it. And I could select r and t separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add css font-variant-ligatures:no-common-ligatures (or font-variant-ligatures:none) to prevent Chrome (and Firefox!) from displaying 'r' that way. IE/Edge don't have the bug.

You could also insert &#8204; between every pair 'rt' and 'rf' (the problem shows in it, too) in the source text (it's invisible), to make browsers think that the characters are not adjacent, but that's a bit of mess.

And I could select r and t separately.

Answer (score 8):

To get the arch of the R above the crossbar of the T, I imagine. The E and A are lower and rounded, so the R fits into their negative space, but the T pokes to the left.

It's *really* noticeable. It's irritating my eye quite a bit. The designer(s) did not do a good job with that ligature pair.